# Plotting a function in 3D using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I want to plot this function as 3D plots in MATLAB for two cases, can anyone help me out? Thank you.

```
f(x,y) = (1-x) + ((2x - 1) y / k)
```

where

case 1)

```
x = [0,1]  // closed unit interval with real values
y = [0,1]  // closed unit interval with real values
k = 10 is a constant
```

case 2)

```
x has domain [0,1] // closed unit interval with real values
y has domain [0,1] // closed unit interval with real values
k has domain [0,1] // closed unit interval with real values
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Read this and then as about any specific issues: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/learn_matlab/plots.html#btbe4cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
%Case 1:
x = 0:.05:1;
n = numel(x);
y = x';
X = repmat(x,n,1);
Y = repmat(y,1,n);
f = @(x,y) (1-x)+((2*x-1).*y)/10;
v = f(X,Y);
figure;mesh(x,y,v);

%Case 2:
x = 0:.05:1;
n = numel(x);
y = x';
X = repmat(x,n,1);
Y = repmat(y,1,n);
figure;
for k = x
    f = @(x,y) (1-x)+((2*x-1).*y)/k;
    v = f(X,Y);
    hold on;
    mesh(x,y,v);
end
```

If you want to plot a surface instead of a mesh replace `mesh` with `surf`, if you want a finer mesh (more detail and more functions plotted in case 2) change the middle number of `x = 0:.05:1;` to something smaller like `x = 0:.01:1;`, and if you want a coarser mesh (less detail and fewer functions plotted in case 2) change the middle number of `x = 0:.05:1;` to something bigger like `x = 0:.1:1;`.

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:.1:1);
K = 10;
F = (ones(11) - X) + ((2*X - ones(11)) * Y / K);
figure
mesh(F);
```

[image]

for case 2

```
figure
for K 0:.1:1
    F = (ones(11) - X) + ((2*X - ones(11)) * Y / K);
    hold on
    mesh(F);
end
```

[image]

Comment: It's a smart solution, however, you need to change `F = 1-X + ((2*X - 1) * Y / K);` to `F = 1-X + ((2*X - 1) .* Y / K);` to actually plot the function in the question!